# My average function returns nan if there aren't any arguments. How can I get it to return 0 instead?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using a rest parameter, how can I get the last console log to display 0 if there aren't any arguments for my function. The first three console logs are fine and return as expected but the last console log returns NaN

```
function average(...numbers) {
let avg = 0;
for(let num of numbers) {
    avg += num;
    }
avg = avg / numbers.length;
return avg;
}

console.log(average(2, 6));
console.log(average(2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 10));
console.log(average(7, 1432, 12, 13, 100));
console.log(average());
```

Comment: You can't divide by zero, else you'll get `NaN`. Not sure what you're expecting, you wouldn't want to give a default value of `0` anyway; `NaN` *would* be the proper thing to return if no arguments are passed.

Comment: To be specific `0/0`, `x/0`, and `-x/0` would result in `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The average of zero numbers is undefined by definition, so getting `NaN` is perfectly expected.

But if you insist in getting `0` in this case, you will need to special case it, e.g. `if (numbers.length == 0) return 0;`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to explicitly write a special case, you can use the short-circuiting functionality of the logical AND `&&` operator instead:

```js
function average(...values) {
  const { length } = values
  let avg = 0

  for (const value of values) {
    avg += value
  }

  return length && avg / length
}

console.log(average(2, 6))
console.log(average(2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 10))
console.log(average(7, 1432, 12, 13, 100))
console.log(average())
```